# Onclick event not working over <option> tag in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onclick

```
<select class="form-control" id="list7" onblur="document.getElementById('lista7').selectedIndex = -1;" size="30" class="form-control" style="height: 350px !important;">
   <option onclick="alert('aa');return false;" value="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="font-size: 0.69em;">10325894 DGR STD (5)</option>
</select>
```

This is the code, onClick over an option it should pop an alert, and then show a modal, but is doing nothing and the IE console does not fire anything, this code its working right in chrome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onclick procedure should belong to the Select element - then you pick up the selected option with SelectBox.SelectedIndex... (something like that - look it up)

As far as I know that should then work cross-browser.

Comment: You are right, I had to move the event listener to the select, but it was working just fine in other browsers!

Comment: Yes, that's odd - I always understood that you couldn't do much with option tags except give them a data value. I've never been able to style one...